# Upload to Firebase Hosting not working correctly

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I've just finished building my first web app using AngularJS and Firebase for my real time database. When I run it on localhost everything I want it to do is working good for me. However, when I've loaded it up to Firebase Hosting and gone and opened it, the files haven't loaded correctly.

My CSS file is blank and both my app.js and maincontroller.js files have all of my index.html code in them instead of the JavaScript code that should be there.

Here is a [link](https://ebsi.firebaseapp.com/) to my app so you can see what I am talking about.

I've been unable to find any answers for what is causing this/what I'm doing wrong. If anyone is able to help it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not link us to external links to view code. Please post the code directly on SO.

Comment: Just an update, My CSS is working now. however my .js files still have the index.html code

Comment: I've posted an external link as the problem is not with the code but with firebase hosting. as mentioned in my post the app works fine in localhost however it is during the deploying to firebase it is failing.

Comment: Can you post image of your project folder structure.

Comment: What is the content of firebase.json file?

Comment: @JakeWansink you need to include the [minimum information needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question (as digit already mentions, your `firebase.json` may be a good place to start). Linking to a site, while useful, is not enough. For example: when your problem is fixed (as it seems to be when I click on the link now), your site will work and this question will become useless. While that's not your problem, the Stack Overflow rules are there to ensure the maximum value for all developers, not just you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem, from the source of `index.html`:

```
<script src="projects/web\ design/in.out/public/app.js"></script>
<script src="projects/web\ design/in.out/public/maincontroller.js"></script>
```

You have local path names in your `<script>` tags when they need to be relative to the `public` directory. These should be changed to `/app.js` and `/maincontroller.js` respectively.

Comment: Hey thanks heaps for that. I originally started off with the just app.js and maincontroller.js without the / in the <script> tags so changed the local path.

Comment: also I see you're an engineer for firebase, just want to say I love your work. as a total rookie self taught hobbyist there's no way I could have got my app working as well as it does without your program.