CSS and JS not loading after firebase deploy
I started having this weird issue where a simple html/css/js site just don't work, the deploy was working just before the latest CLI update, I already checked posts like the following without luck:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156281/upload-to-firebase-hosting-not-working-correctly
Images not loading after Firebase hosting deployed
Firebase not displaying css properly
My public side can be seen here
as you can see, non of the resources is being loaded.
Here is my project structure and my firebase.json

and a glimpse of my index file:

and if I just try to browse to one of the assets, I get this:

Any ideas will be highly appreciated

As some people pointed on a reddit sub like this the issue is related to the version of firebase tools, downgrading to firebase-tools@^13.11.1 did the trick!
just run:
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
npm install -g firebase-tools@^13.11.1

